# Is it possible to have 5V output from a GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, pi-zero

I want to make a small rc car using the raspberry pi. I tested the 3.3V and 5V output for the motor and of course I'd really prefer the 5V output, it is much faster.

From what I read, the GPIO pins only provide 3.3V (right?). Is there any way to get a 5V output from a GPIO pin? If not, is there any alternative?

Is it possible to put the motors into the 5V pin and somehow put a switch between which is connected to a GPIO pin? I guess this isn't possible since the 5V would be too much for the GPIO pin..

Comment: You can buy a L9110S motor driver board controllable from the Pi for a UK pound or so from eBay.